# Updating button text with sliding text from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to update a button text on click by sliding the new text from the top. It "pushes" the text and appear.

I've managed to do that, but **when the background is darker, we can see the text appearing outside the button**. How to solve that ? And i can't lower the top value since otherwise the text is still visible when it is removed from the DOM. Here is my code:

```
var i = 1;
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    var $el = $(this);
    $('span').animate({
        'top': '+=20px'
    }, 250, function () {
        $el.html('');
        i++;
        $el.prepend('<span class="b" >' + i + '</span>');
        $('.b').animate({
            'top': '+=20px'
        }, 250);
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
span {
    position: relative;
}
.b {
    top: -20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bsWxL/1/)

**Is there a way to cut the text when it is bigger than the container ?**
Like so:
[image: example]

Comment: Is there a way to cut the text when it is bigger than the container ? Is that another extra question?

Comment: No, that's a possible solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22894359/2533082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use overflow: hidden on the a tag.
http://jsfiddle.net/QG4cx/12/

```
a {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```